# What are some words for something that is not organised?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

What are some words that describe precisely, something that is is not structured, ordered and not a system. However the word I'm looking for is not something like anarchy, I want a more neutral sounding word with no real negative slant/connotations to it.

There is a certain word that I've seen before that I'm looking for, however I can't find it, even after trying numerous thesauruses, which is weird because it's not a very complex word, it's just a bit uncommon.

An example of usage would be:

> Rules do not work in a world that is ***_*__**. Nature is not an organised system it is ***_*__**.

Comment: Avoid posting questions that do not provide clear criteria for useful answers – criteria that guide both answering and voting.

This applies to polls and requests for preferences, such as “what is your favorite ___” or “what are some ___”, for which every response is equally valid. See: “[Should polls be maintained as Community Wiki questions, or should they be closed? – Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75168)”, and “[Real Questions Have Answers – SE Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)”.

Comment: @MrWonderful Avoid using comments for a purpose other than improving the post they are attached to. For example, comments can be used to ask the author for clarification, point out problems, or suggest changes. A better place to post an answer is in the answer box.

Comment: Avoid asking for help remembering a word or phrase you’ve forgotten. This is what we call a “guessing game” question. They’re not a good fit for the site – or, to my knowledge, any SE site. See: “[Let’s Play The Guessing Game – Stack Overflow Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/)”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps not the specific word you're looking for, but **high-entropy** seems to fit your definition.

Comment: Thats it! I was looking for the word, entropy.

Thanks!

Comment: Hmm. I think technically speaking the only reason we can even exist and perceive the universe at all is because we (and the bit we live in) are relatively **low entropy**. High entropy is assumed to be the eventual fate of the universe when everything "evens out" to become a warm soup containing no distinct objects or possibilities for action.

Comment: _Entropy_ may have been the word you were looking for, but it sure as heck doesn't fit in your sentence! (In either spot.) :-)

Comment: @Gnawme, then you need to go for the adjectival form of it, "Entropic".  Of course, it still doesn't work.  Most people think of entropy as being some chaotic destroyer. Any time something loses energy and dilutes it amongst other things, such as in an explosion or falling and breaking or whatever, it's increasing entropy, but it's actually extremely orderly.  Maximum entropy is where nothing ever really changes, because all the energy is spread around so thinly amongst everything that there's just not enough for anything to do anything. The more chaotic a thing is, the less entropy it has.

Comment: Discussions of entropy would better fit Physics.SE than ELU.

Answer (score 8):

I'd say the most suitable word would be "Chaotic"
For a more neutral connotation, you could also try helter-skelter or jumbled.

Answer (score 3):

*Stochasticity* might work. Or are you aiming at *amorphous*?

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of adjectives to characterize a state of disorganization or lack of organization, but most of them have negative connotations: *disorganized*, *chaotic*, …

The ones that feel the least negative to me are: **random**, **haphazard**, **unsystematic**, **irregular**, or **casual**.

Answer (score 1):

In view of the context provided, I believe the best word would be ["unsystematic":](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unsystematic)

> unsystematic - lacking systematic arrangement or method or organization

Saying something was "unsystematic" would be quite neutral, without any negative connotations, because it isn't necessarily "bad" to be unsystematic.

Or, you could try ["haphazardness":](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/haphazardness)

> The quality of lacking any predictable order or plan.

But, is also a pretty neutral word. For example, "The whole haphazardness of this attempt at taking the city amazes me"

Answer (score 1):

Not for nothing, but I would use disorganized or unstructured. Both words are free of slants or connotations and are exactly opposite of the original meaning.

Answer (score 1):

*Organic* might be appropriate in some contexts.

> Some cities have grown organically, others such as those destroyed by bombing during WW2 were designed and built.

Answer (score 0):

## Random

From Merriam Webster:

> without definite aim, direction, rule, or method.